# LLVM-mctoll command not recognized

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I followed the steps on [llvm-mctoll](https://github.com/microsoft/llvm-mctoll) and everything worked but when I tried to finally run the command to run the tool and lift the elf to LLVM IR I got the error:  `'llvm-mctoll' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

This is what I tried:

`llvm-mctoll -d ..\testcases\a.out -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\stdio.h" -o=../testcases/out.ll --output-format=ll`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what cmake command did you use?

Comment: Add <build-dir>/bin to PATH system variable.